# Querying for specific tags

Tags: php, query, tags

I currently have this code that pulls all of the tags and creates a list with links for them:

```
<?php $tags_array = get_tags();
    foreach( $tags_array as $tag) : 
        $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to pull only specific tags by ID though.  I found the `include` parameter for `get_tags()` on the codex, but I can't find an example that shows correct placement and syntax.

I need to query for include="10, 11, 34, 35".  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `array` of arguments with key `include`.

```
$tags = get_tags(array('include' => '10, 11, 34, 35'));
```